# Creating filepath using JAVACC with different tokens

Tags: java, javacc

How would you make a file path using `JAVACC` where some parts of the file had to be kept constant and you needed to keep separate tokens for this? 
For example, if I wanted to go to a directory where there were constants such that the entire directory looked like "[path] [constant] [path]"

My initials thought are I would want the path to consist of a string so 
TOKEN:

```
<IDENTIFIER: (["a"-"z", "A"-"Z"])+>
<NUMBER: (["0"-"9"])+>
<STRING: "\"" (<IDENTIFIER> | <NUMBERS> | " ")+ "\"">
<PATH>: <STRING>
<CONSTANT>: some constant
```

Comment: JavaCC makes parsers, not file paths. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I would suggest putting a # in front of IDENTIFIER, NUMBER, and STRING.  Other than that, I can't make any sense out of the question. Please edit the question with several positive and negative example or close it.